# Remainder theorem question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

If $n$ is an integer, what is the remainder when $$3x^{2n+3}-4x^{2n+2}+5x^{2n+1}-8$$ is divided by $x+1$?

How would we know what the value of $n$ is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The remainder when the polynomial $P(x)$ is divided by the polynomial $x-a$ is $P(a)$.

Here $a=-1$. You will find that the value of $n$ is irrelevant. This is because if $k$ is an integer, then the value of $(-1)^k$ depends only on whether $k$ is odd or even.

Comment: I got -12 after trying it numerous times. The answer is supposedly -20. Did I happen to miscalculate?

Comment: The answer is $-20$. Note that $(-1)^{2n+3}=-1$ because $2n+3$ is odd. Same with $(-1)^{2n+1}$. And $(-1)^{2n+2}=1$. So we get $(-3)+(-4)+(-5)+(-8)$. Maybe after working hard on the "complicated" terms you forgot about the $-8$ at the end of the expression.

Comment: Are there some set rules for determining whether an expression is an odd or even expression? For example, how could we tell that 2n+3 is odd, except from plugging in random integers? Or is that what we're supposed to do? Also, what does 2n+3 being odd have to do with the whole term equaling -1?

Comment: The number $2n+3$ is odd because $2n$ is automatically even, and $3$ is odd, and the sum of an even and an odd is always odd. And as I mentioned in the answer, whether $(-1)^k$ is $-1$ or $1$ depends only on whether $k$ is odd or even. In general, if $k$ is odd, then $(-1)^k=-1$: the product of an odd number of negative numbers is negative. And the product of an even number of negative numbers is positive, because of the rule $(-x)(-y)=xy$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ By the [Remainder Theorem,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem) $\ f(x) \equiv f(c)\pmod{x-c}$ Yours is case $\,c = -1.$

Alternatively $\ {\rm mod}\ x\!-\!c\!:\,\ x\equiv c\,\Rightarrow\, f(x)\equiv f(c)\,$ for all $\,f\in\Bbb Z[x].$

Comment: I keep getting -12, yet the answer is supposedly -20. I plugged in -1 for x.

Comment: @Eric Yes, $\ {-}3 -4-5-8 = -20$

Comment: Do we ignore the subtraction sign before "4x"? "...-4x^(2n+2)..."

Comment: @Eric $\ -4(-1)^{2n+2} = -4(1) = -4 \ $ Generally $\ (-1)^{2k} = ((-1)^2)^k  = 1^k = 1,\,$ and $\, (-1)^{1+2k} = (-1)(-1)^{2k} = (-1)(1) = -1.\ \ $